# Do I need a visa for 23 hour layover in London to visit the city?

Tags: layovers, transit-visas, london, tourist-visas

I have a 23-hour layover in London. I have a valid US visa. Which UK visa do I need for sightseeing during the layover time?

Comment: What kind of US visa do you have? Whst passport will you be travelling on?

Comment: Whatever US Visa he/she has does not affect the equation.

Comment: @PaulofOsawatomie This isn't quite true, landside transits are permitted for certain US visa holders, on a journey to or from the US, provided the journey is structured to require a landside transit. Additionally US permanent residents (which is a kind of "visa" although I admit it would not usually be described as such) can make landside transits on other journeys. Exceptions apply for holders of certain passports such as Iraqi "S" passports or Syrian passports.

Comment: This isn't a literal duplicate but the answer to the other question is detailed enough that I think it suffices.

Comment: @Calchas which US visas do not allow travelers to make landside transits in the UK?